# Select current column when iterating dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with 1k+ columns like this(i cut it).

[image]

I want to iterate the dataframe and check row by row if value is `True` then assign it the `Incident Type`.

How do i get the current column it is iterating to? I thought of something like that:

```
for index,rows in df3.iterrows():
    if df3.loc[index, #current column ] = True:
               df3.loc[index,'Incident Type'] = '#something'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterating over rows in `pandas` should always be used as a last resort as it is quite inefficient. Always to find a way to vectorize your operations over the dataframe, which in this case is quite easy. If you want to set the `Incident Type` column based on the malware type column that has the value `True` you can use the following code:

```
for col in [col for col in df.columns if col.startswith("actions.malware")]:
    df.loc[df[col] == True, "Incident Type"] = col.split(".")[-1]
```

This code loops over all columns in the dataframe where the column name starts with `actions.malware` and sets the value of the `Incident Type` column to the last word after the '.' in the column name only for those rows where the value in that column is `True`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help, do u mind me asking how does your "df[col] == True" in "df.loc[df[col] == True, "Incident Type"]" work? As far as i know shouldnt the 'row' in  loc[row,col] always be an integer?

Comment: There is a different between the `.iloc` and `.loc` method, the first indeed needs integers to select rows/columns whereas the second can use labels as well as boolean indexing (see also the [pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html)).